# MySQL to select row with unique column value comparing with other columns

Tags: mysql, sql, select, where-clause

I don't know how to explain this, I have a table with three column and I need to select rows with column value which is not repeated in other columns.

```
Table:

CREATE TABLE `new_table` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `col1` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `col2` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `col3` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

INSERT INTO `new_table` (`col1`, `col2`, `col3`) VALUES ('red', 'blue', 'red');
INSERT INTO `new_table` (`col1`, `col2`, `col3`) VALUES ('white', 'red', 'yellow');
INSERT INTO `new_table` (`col1`, `col2`, `col3`) VALUES ('red', 'red', 'red');
INSERT INTO `new_table` (`col1`, `col2`, `col3`) VALUES ('yellow', 'blue', 'black');
```

I tried with `xor` in `where` statement.

```
SELECT * FROM new_table WHERE
        col1 LIKE '%red%'
        xor col2 LIKE '%red%'
        xor col3 LIKE '%red%';
```

But I didn't get desired output

```
Output of this code

ID  COL1    COL2    COL3
2   white   red     yellow
3   red     red     red
```

Output which I need

```
ID  COL1    COL2    COL3
2   white   red     yellow
```

And what if I have N-Number of columns, I know this isn't a best database design.But just for knowledge.
[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a830dd/2)

Comment: Normalization, anyone?

Comment: @Strawberry Yeah I know about normalization, But is there anyway to do this at-least for three columns. ?

Comment: Just for knowledge, you wouldn't do it this way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM new_table
WHERE CONCAT( col1,  ' ', col2,  ' ', col3 ) LIKE  "%red%"
AND col1 <> col2
AND col2 <> col3
AND col1 <> col3;
```

Comment: this won't work, I need a value to check using `like`

Comment: Then: SELECT * FROM new_table WHERE CONCAT(col1,' ',col2,' ',col3) like "%red%" AND
col1 <> col2 AND col2 <> col3 AND col1 <> col3;

Comment: I pressed enter before I edited :) Now it it correct.

Comment: Great, yeah this works. If you edit your answer I will accept it.